# How do I create an Accursed Specter?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

The XGE Hexblade Warlock unlocks an ability called *Accursed Specter* at level 6.

> Starting at 6th level, you can curse the soul of a person you slay, temporarily binding it to your service. When you slay a humanoid, you can cause its spirit to rise from its corpse as a specter, the statistics for which are in the Monster Manual.

My confusion here is that it doesn't mention anything about how this is done. I would assume that I just take it as literally as possible, that I need to be the one that deals the killing blow and it just automatically happens if I want it to?

It seems straightforward enough but wanted to make sure there wasn't something I was missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## You didn't miss anything

Like you observe, it is not clearly defined so we can read it plainly. The word "slay" is defined as to...

> kill (a person or animal) in a violent way.

You must be the one to actually kill the humanoid (or deal the killing blow)

Comment: I wonder if the rest of the party could simply knock out enemies and let the Warlock deal the killing blow to the helpless creature.  This seems inherently evil though.

Comment: @NickBrown that would certainly work and I wouldn't say "inherently evil." But certainly ruthless

Comment: I suddenly see bringing slaves to serve as spectre food